# How to change the default fromEmail in mailjet?

Tags: mailjet

I am using Mailjet service for sending email in my node application. 
How  can I change the default Sender name and email. 
I have tried to pass  the fromName and fromEmail in Mailjet send  api function,
but it doesn't work. It is showing the default fromEmail and  FromName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send email from a particular address it should have previously added in your Mailjet administration console.

From [Make yout first request](https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#make-your-first-request):

> First, you need to have at least one active sender address in the
>   Mailjet system. Visit the Sender domains & addresses section to check
>   and setup your domain and sender.

You have 2 options at [Sender domains & addresses](https://app.mailjet.com/account/sender)

### Option 1: add a domain

> Configuring a whole domain ensures that all your sender addresses tied
>   to that domain name will be automatically validated when they show up
>   for the first time in our system.

### Option 2: add individual email addresses

> This is the fastest way for small websites. This is also recommended
>   if you are using a free web host and don't have FTP access.

Comment: Thanks. Can we add the fromEmail dynamically ? That  means while sending email . Is there any api to add the fromEmail dynamically ?

Comment: You can configure a domain and any email address from that domain will be able to send email through mailjet: "Configuring a whole domain ensures that all your sender addresses tied to that domain name will be automatically validated when they show up for the first time in our system."